# Manipulating breadcrumb bar content

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a select list as a page item on my breadcrumb bar and I want to alight it to the far right. I tried adding static regions - unfortunately static regions in the breadcrumb bar do not have all the properties of the static regions on the content part of the page. How can I manipulate items on the breadcrumb bar?

I also wanted to add subtext to the breadcrumb bar under the breadcrumb title. Would appreciate any help

Comment: This won't help at all, but - as there are no answers *for hours*, here you go: I use the breadcrumb region for what it name suggests - *breadcrumbs*. Why did you put that item in there? Is there no other place you could use? Apex offers quite a few region types to choose among. I'd try one-by-one and see which one suits the best. Consider **page 0** (global page) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, which was quite simple. When viewing page source I found a section `t-HeroRegion-col--right` (Hero is the template I am using for the breadcrumb region). In order to get items into that region I added a static region to the breadcrumb sub regions (apparently it automatically gets set to the righ-hand side of the breadcrumb region) and then moved my select list into thta static region and now it appears to the right of the title just as I wanted. Posting this here in case someone else will find it useful